# How to create Spark DataFrame from RDD[Row] when Row contains complex types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD[HbaseRecord]` which contains a custom complex type `Name`.  Both classes are defined below:

```
class HbaseRecord(
      val uuid: String,
      val timestamp: String,
      val name: Name
)

class Name(    
    val firstName:                String,     
    val middleName:               String,       
    val lastName:                 String
)
```

At some point in my code I want to generate a DataFrame from that RDD, so I can save it as an avro file. I tried the following:

```
//I get an Object from Hbase here
val objectRDD : RDD[HbaseRecord] = ... 

//I convert the RDD[HbaseRecord] into RDD[Row]
val rowRDD : RDD[Row] = objectRDD .map(
    hbaseRecord => {
      val uuid : String = hbaseRecord.uuid
      val timestamp : String = hbaseRecord.timestamp
      val name : Name = hbaseRecord.name

      Row(uuid, timestamp, name)
    })

//Here I define the schema
   val schema = new StructType()
                  .add("uuid",StringType)
                  .add("timestamp", StringType)
                  .add("name", new StructType()
                                  .add("firstName",StringType)
                                  .add("middleName",StringType)
                                  .add("lastName",StringType)

//Now I try to create a Dataframe using the RDD[Row] and the schema
val dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD , schema)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> scala.MatchError:  (of class java.lang.String)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried removing the complex type from the Row, so it would be `Row[String, String]` and there is no error then. So I assume the problem is with the complex type.

What am I doing wrong? or what other approach could I follow to generate that DataFrame with the complex type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used simple `case class` for this instead of class.
`name` column didn't conform to the schema that was defined.
Convert the `name` column to Row type and it should work.

```
val rowRDD : RDD[Row] = objectRDD .map(
    hbaseRecord => {
      val uuid : String = hbaseRecord.uuid
      val timestamp : String = hbaseRecord.timestamp
      val name = Row(hbaseRecord.name.firstName,
                     hbaseRecord.name.middleName,hbaseRecord.name.lastName)
      Row(uuid, timestamp, name)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. And about the schema to generate the dataframe, should I change something??

Comment: No but it depends on what you need. Check the output and then you can decide.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I would like to ask you as well, how would it be in the case of an array of maps? I guess the Row would keep representing the name map, but how could I specify there is an array of names?

Comment: Please post a different question and your expectations(data, schema and output).