# How to create Spark DataFrame from RDD[Row] when Row contains Map[Map]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

> This question is the continuation of this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55206721/1773841), where the user
>   who gave the valid answer requested a new question to explain my further doubts.

What I am trying is to generate a dataframe from a `RDD[Objects]` where my objects has got primitive types, but also complex types. In the previous questions it was explained how to parse a complex type Map.

What I tried next is to extrapolate the given solution to parse a Map[Map]. So in the DataFrame it is converted into a Array(Map).

Below I give the code I have written so far:

```
//I get an Object from Hbase here
val objectRDD : RDD[HbaseRecord] = ... 

//I convert the RDD[HbaseRecord] into RDD[Row]
val rowRDD : RDD[Row] = objectRDD.map(
    hbaseRecord => {

        val uuid : String = hbaseRecord.uuid
        val timestamp : String = hbaseRecord.timestamp

        val name = Row(hbaseRecord.nameMap.firstName.getOrElse(""),
            hbaseRecord.nameMap.middleName.getOrElse(""),
            hbaseRecord.nameMap.lastName.getOrElse(""))

        val contactsMap = hbaseRecord.contactsMap 

        val homeContactMap = contactsMap.get("HOME")
        val homeContact = Row(homeContactMap.contactType,
            homeContactMap.areaCode,
            homeContactMap.number)

        val workContactMap = contactsMap.get("WORK")
        val workContact = Row(workContactMap.contactType,
            workContactMap.areaCode,
            workContactMap.number)

        val contacts = Row(homeContact,workContact)

        Row(uuid, timestamp, name, contacts)

    }
)


//Here I define the schema
   val schema = new StructType()
                    .add("uuid",StringType)
                    .add("timestamp", StringType)
                    .add("name", new StructType()
                            .add("firstName",StringType)
                            .add("middleName",StringType)
                            .add("lastName",StringType)
                    .add("contacts", new StructType(
                                   Array(
                                   StructField("contactType", StringType),
                                   StructField("areaCode", StringType),
                                   StructField("number", StringType)
                    )))  


//Now I try to create a Dataframe using the RDD[Row] and the schema
val dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD , schema)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> 19/03/18 12:09:53 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in
>   stage 1.0 (TID 8) scala.MatchError: [HOME,05,12345678] (of class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried as well to generate the contacts element as an array:

```
val contacts = Array(homeContact,workContact)
```

But then I get the following error instead:

> scala.MatchError: [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;@726c6aec (of class
>   [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;)

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify your situation to your array of contacts. That's where the problem is. You are trying to use this schema:

```
val schema = new StructType()
                .add("contacts", new StructType(
                               Array(
                               StructField("contactType", StringType),
                               StructField("areaCode", StringType),
                               StructField("number", StringType)
                )))
```

to store a list of contacts, which is a struct type. Yet, this schema cannot contain a list, just one contact. We can verify it with:

```
spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq[Row]()), schema).printSchema
root
 |-- contacts: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contactType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- areaCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
```

Indeed, the `Array` you have in your code is just meant to contain the fields of your "contacts" struct type.

To achieve what you want, a type exists: `ArrayType`. This yields a slightly different result:

```
val schema_ok = new StructType()
    .add("contacts", ArrayType(new StructType(Array(
        StructField("contactType", StringType),
        StructField("areaCode", StringType),
        StructField("number", StringType)))))

spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq[Row]()), schema_ok).printSchema
root
 |-- contacts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- contactType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- areaCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
```

and it works:

```
val row = Row(Array(
                Row("type", "code", "number"), 
                Row("type2", "code2", "number2")))
spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(row)), schema_ok).show(false)
+-------------------------------------------+
|contacts                                   |
+-------------------------------------------+
|[[type,code,number], [type2,code2,number2]]|
+-------------------------------------------+
```

So if you update the schema with this version of "contacts", just replace `val contacts = Row(homeContact,workContact)` by `val contacts = Array(homeContact,workContact)` and it should work.

NB: if you want label your contacts (with HOME or WORK), there exists a `MapType` type as well.